# What exactly a hybrid can do and can not do

Tags: server, windows-server-2019, azure-hybrid-connections

[azure] simple question. What exactly a hybrid can do and can not do? I have a Win Server 2019 on premises. Does a hybrid Win Server in Azure acts as a mirrow  of my premises server? I have an accounting software running on the premises server and will like to explore how will the azure provides a way for remote clients to access the accounting file using Remote desktop